# How to write a C# client RPC to a remote native C++ server?

Tags: c#, com, rpc

I have to implement a C# client, accessing a native C++ server.exe, which has RPC interfaces,running on a remote computer.

What's the recommend way of doing this?

My thoughts are:

1. Write a C++ dll on client side, communicate with server using RPC, exposing its interface through COM, then C# access COM interfaces.(I'v experience all the way around.)
2. Write a C++ dll on client side, communicate with server using RPC, wrap interface in C++ CLR, then C# access them directly.(not familiar with C++ CLR wrapper)

Are there more direct way to do this? I've googled some other terms like Remoting and it's successor WCF, then DCOM, are they something I can make use of ?

My criteria is the simple the better, since I'm a lazy programmer. And new tech is preferred if possible, I mean I would use WCF instead of Remoting, if WCF is the new replacement for Remoting.

Comment: WCF has been the replacement for Remoting for six years.

Answer (score 2):

Probably the simplest option would be to write a C++ DLL on client side which communicates with the server using RPC, and have C# call functions in the DLL through pinvoke. The main task here would be to set up the marshalling of the function parameters between managed and native. The complexity of that task depends on how complex the interface is.

Comment: Thank you for you answer. I thought there may be some kind of more direct way for C# to access C++ RPC server, but now I know there ain't.